# W2k3 Custom Services Slowness

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows, .net-4.0

i am using sc.exe to create a custom exe windows service (auto start enabled) into a Windows 2003 SP2 machine and it runs very very very slow compare if i uses the same application and run it using a command prompt.

both the service and the dos program shared the same DLL and all these coded using .NET 4 C# programming language.

can anyone point any possible investigation?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a closer look at the security situation/environment of the service against the account used to compare against interactively (logged on session). If there are security issues, then the performance difference may be due to additional logging and/or error handling.

Comment: I had tried doing the same on another box - Windows 2008 and the performance is greater difference of the later

Comment: In that case, have you compared the running processes across both systems?

Comment: yes, tried run on w2k8 on both Windows Services and command prompt, both also faster than the W2k3 instance.

although the w2k3 box hardware spec is lower than the w2k8, but the funny thing is under w2k3 box, the command prompt executable is faster than installed Windows Service.

Comment: "have you compared the running processes across both systems" - what services are running on the systems for comparison?

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, you are referring to other Windows services that affects the slowness of my custom windows service?

Comment: Yes. What is the inventory of running processes between the systems being compared?

Comment: I checked, nothing special but just some standard default installation services.

Comment: Well, then there is something with the 2003 installation. You might consider refreshing its installation or hosting your application on a different functioning installation.

Comment: might need to arrange for that since the w2k3 machine is sitting in production live

Comment: You might consider options in bringing up its refresh-replacement in parallel off-line and then "swinging" it into production in place of the current system.